# Problem with keosd connection via http rpc

Tags: rpc, docker, keosd

I start nodeos and keosd as docker image. nodeos is listening on 8888, keosd - 8900.
When I work via cleos - this is normal.
When I get chain_info - nodeos get me normal info.
When I get wallet_list - keosd not answer me. There was "connection reset by peer".
There is start logs from keosd:

```
2018-08-22T12:09:18.075 thread-0 http_plugin.cpp:344 plugin_initialize ] configured http to listen on 127.0.0.1:8900
2018-08-22T12:09:18.076 thread-0 wallet_plugin.cpp:42 plugin_initialize ] initializing wallet plugin
2018-08-22T12:09:18.076 thread-0 http_plugin.cpp:447 add_handler ] add api url: /v1/keosd/stop
2018-08-22T12:09:18.076 thread-0 http_plugin.cpp:401 plugin_startup ] start listening for http requests
2018-08-22T12:09:18.076 thread-0 wallet_api_plugin.cpp:73 plugin_startup ] starting wallet_api_plugin
2018-08-22T12:09:18.076 thread-0 http_plugin.cpp:447 add_handler ] add api url: /v1/wallet/create
2018-08-22T12:09:18.076 thread-0 http_plugin.cpp:447 add_handler ] add api url: /v1/wallet/create_key
2018-08-22T12:09:18.076 thread-0 http_plugin.cpp:447 add_handler ] add api url: /v1/wallet/get_public_keys
2018-08-22T12:09:18.076 thread-0 http_plugin.cpp:447 add_handler ] add api url: /v1/wallet/import_key
2018-08-22T12:09:18.076 thread-0 http_plugin.cpp:447 add_handler ] add api url: /v1/wallet/list_keys
2018-08-22T12:09:18.076 thread-0 http_plugin.cpp:447 add_handler ] add api url: /v1/wallet/list_wallets
2018-08-22T12:09:18.076 thread-0 http_plugin.cpp:447 add_handler ] add api url: /v1/wallet/lock
2018-08-22T12:09:18.076 thread-0 http_plugin.cpp:447 add_handler ] add api url: /v1/wallet/lock_all
2018-08-22T12:09:18.076 thread-0 http_plugin.cpp:447 add_handler ] add api url: /v1/wallet/open
2018-08-22T12:09:18.076 thread-0 http_plugin.cpp:447 add_handler ] add api url: /v1/wallet/remove_key
2018-08-22T12:09:18.076 thread-0 http_plugin.cpp:447 add_handler ] add api url: /v1/wallet/set_timeout
2018-08-22T12:09:18.076 thread-0 http_plugin.cpp:447 add_handler ] add api url: /v1/wallet/sign_digest
2018-08-22T12:09:18.076 thread-0 http_plugin.cpp:447 add_handler ] add api url: /v1/wallet/sign_transaction
2018-08-22T12:09:18.076 thread-0 http_plugin.cpp:447 add_handler ] add api url: /v1/wallet/unlock
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you copy paste the error you are getting after running the cleos wallet command?

Comment: cleos wallet command work perfect, problem with http rpc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with server listening. keosd was listening localhost, but when I make request at localhost, there was not a localhost for docker.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will copy keosd from docker, and put it in the same directory of cleos.

When call cleos to interact with wallet, keosd will be launched by cleos.